# How do I get ts2gas to emit ES6 code for Google Apps Script projects?

Tags: typescript, google-apps-script, clasp

Recently Google Apps Script (GAS) changed over to using V8 internally.

I've been using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/), [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/), [Google Clasp](https://github.com/google/clasp) and a tool called [ts2gas](https://github.com/grant/ts2gas) to develop GAS projects.

The current workflow uploads a transpiled ES3 version of my ES6 source code to Google.

What I'm asking is this: how do I get the transpiler to start outputting more V8-ish code? I have lots of "const" and "let" but the transpiler invariably changes them to "var". Anything that is more recent than ES3 gets converted to an ES3 workalike. Are there settings in `tsconfig.json` (for example) that will make this happen?

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation (README.MD) in the `clasp` [github repo](https://github.com/google/clasp), you need to set the `target` property to `2019` in `tsconfig.json` and ensure that the v8 runtime is enabled for your apps script project (in `appscript.json`).

Comment: However using the latest clasp and the latest VSCode, I get a wavy line under "2019" (and not with "ES2019"). However, neither seems to make much difference as all my "const" are still converted to "var".

Comment: @bug install clasp with `@latest`

Answer (score 1):

Under ts2gas [advanced](https://github.com/grant/ts2gas#advanced) options the default target is 'ES3'. You could change that to 'ES6' and see if that works to get the output you want?